# How to determine the Jordan form and give a Jordan base for a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

given is

$\begin{pmatrix} 3&0&-1&0&0 \\ 1&3&0&1&0 \\ 0&0&3&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&3&0 \\ 0&0&0&0&-3 \end{pmatrix}$

I have to determine the jordan form and also give a jordanbase.

I got this so far:

1. Eigenvalues are
   $l_1 = 3, l_2 = -3$ whereas $P_A(x) = (x-3)^4 * (x+3)$.
2. Eigenvectors are
   for $l_1 = 3$:
   $(0,1,0,0,0)$ and $(-1,0,0,1,0)$

for $l_2 = -3$:
$(0,0,0,0,1)$

3. This means, that we still need two vectors. How can I get them?
4. How can I get then the jordanbase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the full base, you need the [generalized eigenvectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector). In this case, we do so as follows:

I define
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{
3&0&-1&0&0 \\ 
1&3&0&1&0 \\ 
0&0&3&0&0 \\ 
0&0&0&3&0 \\ 
0&0&0&0&-3
}
$$
We find non-zero solutions to the following:
$$
(A - 3I)x = \pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\0\\0} \implies
x = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\0\\0}\\
(A - 3I)x = \pmatrix{-1\\0\\0\\1\\0} \implies
\text{no solution}\\
(A - 3I)x = \pmatrix{1\\0\\0\\0\\0} \implies
x = \pmatrix{0\\0\\-1\\0\\0}\\
$$
And we now have a base.  Our Jordan form $J = S^{-1}AS$ must be
$$
J = \pmatrix{3&1\\&3&1\\&&3\\&&&3\\&&&&-3}
$$
with base
$$
S = \pmatrix{0&1&0&-1&0\\1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&-1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1}
$$

Comment: Wow thank you =) What would happen if there was no solution in each of these cases?

Comment: That would mean that our matrix doesn't have a Jordan canonical form... which is impossible.

Comment: If there was a solution to the first equation, I would have two Jordan blocks of size 2 (rather than one of size 3).